# Is there any viable alternative of MiniProfiler for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, profiling

In older ASP.NET projects I used to include [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com), which displayed a neat table of execution times of measured methods. However, it does not work with .NET Core. Is there a viable alternative?

I know about Application Insights in Visual Studio, or dotTrace and dotMemory from JetBrains. However, I do not need to measure memory leaks, performance, etc. I really just need to annotate or inject pieces of code into critical controller and business layer methods, which are calling a 3rd party API and measure, how long did individual parts of code execute.

Comment: there will be glimpse if they ever get around to releasing it https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype

Comment: Thanks, but I need something that actually works right now :D

Comment: FYI, there's a v4 branch of mini-profiler that you might want to try: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/v4

Answer (score 3):

[MiniProfiler for .NET V4](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/) supports .NET Core (for both [ASP.NET Core](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore) and [console applications](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ConsoleDotNetCore)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a profiling/self-profiling API in dotTrace, it is compatible with .NET Core and could meet your requirements: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2016.3/Profiling_Guidelines__Advanced_Profiling_Using_dotTrace_API.html

Comment: I've never managed to get dotTrace working with .NET Core apps. Upgraded to 2017.1.1 today, and it still doesn't work. Profiling seems to start, but when the application ends no results are displayed.

Comment: @Cocowalla I strongly recommend you to submit a support request at https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66771 page. dotTrace supports .NET Core profiling.